# Apache camel endpoint handling

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf, spring-dsl

I have an `applicationContext` xml file that imports multiple resources (camel context files).

```
<import resource="AddRequest.xml" >              
<import resource="AdviseRequest.xml" >
```

I am caching the definitions of this xml before hand using `new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext()`.

Say `AddRequest.xml` uses some method to connect to some host, while  `AdviseRequest.xml` uses `CXF` endpoint to `SOAP`.

When I try to load the `applicationContext xml`, it tries to caches both files first before actually starting `camelContext`. At this stage, it is trying to check the `CXF` endpoint availabilty. Is there anyway to handle this, if the `soap wsdl` is actually down ?

The reason is, if there's some connection issues in the second xml, my first xml also fails, as it tries to cache both at a time.

Note: I cannot use two separate `applicationContext` files

I have used below code in the camel route.

```
<onException id="Request_onException1">
      <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
      <handled>
          <constant>true</constant>
      </handled>

</onException>
```